# Push element in the opposite direction if space is available

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm writing a form with CSS Grid Layout and trying to align inputs at same level. Fields will have label for name and error, and each field could have none, one or both.

Currently, I have this:

[image: form error css grid layout]

Want it like this:

[image: form desired style css grid layout]

So if there is space available up or down the element should be pushed in opposite direction in order to keep fields aligned always.

This is CSS for form tag:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 16px;

    & > :nth-child(3),
    & > :nth-child(4),
    & > :nth-child(7) {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }

    & > * {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Here the basic composition of the HTML (using React so I'm putting just the important tags):

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
}

form > :nth-child(3),
form > :nth-child(4),
form > :nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

& > * {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.error {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="content"> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
        <span class="label">Label</span> <!-- Span rendered only if exists -->
        <input />
        <!-- Span not rendered when there is no value -->
    </div>
    <div class="content"> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
      <!-- Span not rendered if no label value exists -->
      <input />
      <span class="error">Error</span> <!-- Span rendered if exists -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML as well or better yet a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JHeth I updated it. Does that works?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in pure css, In order to push either one we need to check the one next to it, And there's no direct way to do checks in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having fixed height for span (label or error) unless it can be multiple lines

```css
form {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 16px;
  display: grid;
}

form > :nth-child(3),
form > :nth-child(4),
form > :nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

form > * {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form > div > span {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <span>Label</span> <!-- Label if exists -->
    <input />
    <span></span> <!-- Error if exists -->
</div>
<div> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <span></span> <!-- Label if exists -->
    <input />
    <span>Error</span> <!-- Error if exists -->
</div>
<div> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <span>Label</span> <!-- Label if exists -->
    <input />
    <span></span> <!-- Error if exists -->
</div>
<div> <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <span>Label</span> <!-- Label if exists -->
    <input />
    <span></span> <!-- Error if exists -->
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I updated the question in order to show no span rendering when there is no value. So, span tag will be rendered only if has a string value !== "". Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So I considered this as the best approach. Whenever labels don't get rendered the space will be deleted in form rendering. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your already using the content div to wrap the label and it already has `display: flex` you can just add `margin-top: auto` to the input field and make the error message `position: absolute` and place it below the input. This way the input will always be at the bottom of the div and the error span will always be rendered below.

Just make sure to allow some extra space in between rows of inputs for the error to show.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
}

form> :nth-child(3),
form> :nth-child(4),
form> :nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

&>* {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.error {
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

input {
  margin-top: auto
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <span class="label">Label</span>
    <!-- Span rendered only if exists -->
    <input />
    <!-- Span not rendered when there is no value -->
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Each form's child is a div which contains labels and input -->
    <!-- Span not rendered if no label value exists -->
    <input />
    <span class="error">Error</span>
    <!-- Span rendered if exists -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This will make rows to have a fixed height. So spacing between first and second row will be bigger than the expected when both errors from first row are not visible.

Comment: I would prefer fixed height rows of inputs especially if the error is conditional and can show up and go away. If you're accounting for the height of that error in your layout then you will have a lot of layout shift during form interactions which is terrible UX.